# How to transfer ERC20 tokens to another address using solidity?

Tags: solidity, polygon, erc20

I create ERC20 tokens, and i want to transfer my tokens to another address.

I have two accounts in my metamask.(Account A/B)

My ERC20 code's here (I deployed and save tokens in **account A**)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name,symbol) {
        // mint 1000 token
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000*10**uint(decimals()));
    }
}
```

**Question : how can I transfer my ERC20 tokens from the current address to another? (A->B)**

I use this code in **account A**, but not work.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TokenTransfer {
    IERC20 _token;

    // token = MyToken's contract address
    constructor(address token) public {
        _token = IERC20(token);
    }
    
    // to = Account B's address
    function stake(address to, uint amount) public {
        _token.approve(address(this), amount);
        
        require(_token.allowance(address(this), address(this)) >= amount);
        _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, to, amount);
    }
}
```

error message

```
transact to TokenTransfer.stake errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": 3,
  "message": "execution reverted: ERC20: insufficient allowance",
  "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d45524332303a20696e73756666696369656e7420616c6c6f77616e6365000000"
}
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your logic is wrong!
If you want to send a token from account A to account B without passing from smart contract, you can use 'Send' options available in Metamask and other wallet.
If you want use a smart contract, your logic change.
In your smart contract code, there are some errors:

- `_token.approve(address(this), amount)`: when you write this statement, you're approving smart contract itself to move your tokens but it doesn't have any token! Another thing about `approve()` function. This operation must be do from user, in details a person must to give to smart contract permission accessing about his wallet;
- Another error is: smart contract cannot failt to have a function about deposit token to call from account A. In this case, when you write this statament, `_token.transferFrom(msg.sender, to, amount);`, (`msg.sender` is smart contract) you cannot transfer any amount to receiver address because smart contract doesn't have the amount of tokens.
- Last problem, is when you transfer a token from smart contract to address you must use `transfer()` function instead `transferFrom()` because this last function require approve + transfer and smart contracts cannot approve itself. While `transfer()` is used only transfer funds.

To resolve this problems, you can see this smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TokenTransfer {
    IERC20 _token;

    // token = MyToken's contract address
    constructor(address token) {
        _token = IERC20(token);
    }

    // Modifier to check token allowance
    modifier checkAllowance(uint amount) {
        require(_token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= amount, "Error");
        _;
    }

    // In your case, Account A must to call this function and then deposit an amount of tokens 
    function depositTokens(uint _amount) public checkAllowance(_amount) {
        _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }
    
    // to = Account B's address
    function stake(address to, uint amount) public {
        _token.transfer(to, amount);
    }

    // Allow you to show how many tokens owns this smart contract
    function getSmartContractBalance() external view returns(uint) {
        return _token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It's just what I was looking for! Thanks Antonio.

I'm trying to use visual code + remix + ganache and if I run this code, the GetSmartContractBalance function gives me error "there are errors sending the data". Unfortunately the error message doesn't help.
I entered the address of a known token (TUSD,...) but without success. Do you have suggestions?
thanks Lorenzo

Comment: Please, you open another thread on StackOverflow with adding more details about your issue.